# V-222665 - uncategorized or emerging mobile code

Tags: javascript, security, fortify, stig

I have this STIG finding from a Fortify scan telling me that many of my embedded JavaScript files are not secure.  Can someone please explain why this is a finding and how to overcome it?

*"The designer must ensure uncategorized or emerging mobile code is not used in applications."*

The code is local to the web application and is not pulled from any external location.